# How to copy multiple rows (value Only) within the same sheet by Google App Script for Google Sheet

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, range, rows

I like to copy multiple rows value from and to the same google sheet by a script, but I failed to get it to work.

My script:

```
function Copymultiplerows() { 
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("Spreadsheeturl");
    Logger.log(ss.getName());
    var mysheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    var source = ss.getRange ('72:350');
    var tss =SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("Spreadsheeturl");                            
    var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    ts.getRange('73:351'); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to get and set the values

```
ts.getRange("73:351").setValues(source.getValues());
```

Comment: Thanks Robin, I added the get and set value code , but when I ran the script, it returns an error message, it says   " Incorrect range width, was 106 but should be 128 (line 8, file "Code")Dismiss"  , what should I do in view of this? Cheers

Comment: One of your sheets has more columns than the other (might be empty). You might wan to use `source = ss.getDataRange().getValues()` and then `ts.getRange(1,1, source.length, source[0].length).setValues(source)`

Comment: Hi Robin, thanks for your suggestion, maybe my question (codes ) are confusing. I want to copy rows on the same sheet, so the columns total should be identical.   To clarify, I update the data value on row 72 on a daily basis & like to make a script to  keep a record of the updated row 72 data by copying it down to row 73 and along with it move the original data from row 73 to 350 down to 74 to 351 ( a time trigger will do the job), am thinking an alternative will be to copy row 72 and insert the copied row under it (to row 73), I shall be grateful if you can help with code for it. Cheers.

Comment: It's not about the data but what's in the sheet, if one spreadsheet has columns A:Z and the other A:BD the ranges you'll selected with 73:351 are different

Comment: Thanks Robin, I added the code above but it didnt work, will try to keep looking for a workaround and will post it here once I have found them, cheers!

Comment: Can you share a spreadsheet where this happens as an example please?